# AJAX not updating on other activity

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to update certain data in a page on change of another data using AJAX. How can I achieve. The AJAX gets me the data for the first time. But doesnt update when the other data is changed.

EDIT: I have to update a data based on another event on the same page. Briefly explaining the scenario, a particular event updates my DB with an AJAX call. And another AJAX call displays that DB content. So want to update the display event after the change event. How to complement the 2 AJAX calls without function calls.

PLEASE SEE : Cant share the code because of Non Disclosure Agreement.

Comment: i think you are looking for eventdelegation

Comment: Yes @madalinivascu . I have to update a data based on another event on the page. Briefly explaining the scenario, a particular event updates my DB with an AJAX call. And another AJAX call displays that DB content. So want to update the display event after the change event. How to complement the 2 AJAX calls without function calls.

Comment: do you know what event delegation is? why are you doing 2 ajax calls and not just one send data to db with ajax on successful save take the data from the  db with the same server side script and output it to the page with the use of the ajax success function

Comment: i thing you can call the display ajax on success of change ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you're trying to do is chain your ajax calls. Jquery has a technique for this. Something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'somepage.cgi',
    data: {foo: 'bar'}
}).done(function() {
    // this will be run when the AJAX request succeeds
}).fail(function() {
    // this will be run when the AJAX request fails
}).always(function() {
    // this will be run when the AJAX request is complete, whether it fails or succeeds
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someotherpage.cgi',
        data: {foo: 'bar'}
    })
});
```

See eg http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).
>   These methods take one or more function arguments that are called when
>   the $.ajax() request terminates. This allows you to assign multiple
>   callbacks on a single request, and even to assign callbacks after the
>   request may have completed. (If the request is already complete, the
>   callback is fired immediately.) Available Promise methods of the jqXHR
>   object include: ...